# RxJava2 execute bunch of Completables in parallel and wait all to complete

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I want to execute several blocking methods (network calls, computation tasks). I want to execute them **in parallel** and be notified when ALL of them complete or receive an error if ANY of them fails (throws an exception). They do not emit results so `Observable.zip()` is not going to help me.

So far I have:

```
Completable a = computationTaskA();
Completable b = computationTaskB();
Completable c = computationTaskC();
Completable all = Completable.concat(Arrays.asList(a, b, c))
            .subscribe(() -> {
               // all succeed
            }, e -> {
               // any fails
            });
```

However `Completable.concat()` docs say `Returns a Completable which completes only when all sources complete, one after another.`. I do not find a solution that would execute them in parallel.

Comment: Have you looked at the available operators and static factory methods of `Completable`?

Comment: I've looked at https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Combining-Observables and couldn't figure it out. Do you have something particular in mind?

Comment: https://solidsoft.wordpress.com/2016/02/26/parallel-execution-of-blocking-tasks-with-rxjava-and-completable/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You probably want to use [`Completable.merge/mergeArray`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#mergeArray-io.reactivex.CompletableSource...-)

```
Completable a = computationTaskA();
Completable b = computationTaskB();
Completable c = computationTaskC();
Completable all = Completable.mergeArray(a, b, c);

all.subscribe(
    () -> { /* success all around! */ },
    e -> { /* at least one failure :( */ }
);
```